# static ofstream will create a file but never write to it?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a function that writes some data to a file:

```
void log(const std::string& data) 
{
    std::ofstream out_file{ "data.txt", std::ofstream::app };
    out_file << data;
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However, the second I change the `out_file` declaration to `static`, it will create the `data.txt` file, but it will never actually write any data to it.

No exceptions will ever be thrown, yet the file will always remain empty even when the log function is called several times. If I remove `static`, the logging function will work normally and write to the file.

This function is being called inside a low level keyboard hook callback. MSDN states that: `This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it.` so it shouldn't be a thread related issue.

Comment: The most likely answer is that you terminate your program in an abnormal manner that does not result in an orderly destruction of global static objects, and thus flushing the internal stream buffer. Either fix that, or do an explicit `std::flush`.

Comment: @Sam The program never gets terminated unless it is manually closed. The main message loop is always being called.

Comment: Does it do this without the hook?

Comment: @chris No it does not.

Comment: The fact that a manual action is require to terminate the program doesn't mean that it's done in a manner that's orderly. For example, I could also write a program, on Linux, that's "manually closed" by `SIGKILL`ing itself. The likelyhood of my program actually getting terminated in a manner that provides for orderly destruction of global object would be approximately 0%. Unless you call `exit`, or return from `main`, you have no guarantees.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The execution of the log function would have finished long before I close the program. The destruction of global objects is not the issue here. The program will continue running for several minutes after the log function was called before being manually closed.

Comment: This is incorrect. There is no guarantee that the `<<` operator will physically write the formatted output to the file, for the simple reason that `std::ofstream` uses an internal stream buffer, and it would only get flushed to the actual file in certain circumstances. Just because "the execution of the log function would have finished", doesn't mean that anything is actually guaranteed to be written to the actual file. That's not how file streams work. You must either flush them explicitly, or properly close/destroy them. What part of that is unclear to you?

Comment: When it is non-static, the stream object gets destroyed as part of leaving its scope by returning from the log function. That's why everything gets written out correctly, in that case.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you very much, flushing the buffer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the proper destruction of the global object that was not guaranteed. By adding the following to my code:

```
out_file << data << std::flush;
```

It all works as expected.